# Can I use a universal power adapter for this old Ikea lamp?

Tags: lighting, lamp, adapter, power-supply, ikea

I bought this old Ikea lamp from a thrift store the other day, but it is missing its original power adapter. It's got this plug that looks like an old RCA cable. I saw on reddit that the original adapter is called a KUA1200200L, but the only ones I could find for sale online would cost almost $100 after shipping so I'd like to find an alternative.

So I'm wondering, would there be any universal power adapters I could get that would work for this? For instance, I found [this power supply on Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/EverBright-Adapter-Listed-Transformer-Converter/dp/B08BHXT7B2/ref=sr_1_2?crid=11X7VNYJGPPJF&keywords=everbright%2012v%205a&qid=1695136710&sprefix=everbright%2012v%205a%2Caps%2C103&sr=8-2) - would this work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A simple search for   KUA1200200L  found at least two for less than 30 bucks on amazon.

Answer (score 4):

If you can sort out what the voltage and current required are, sure. The label doen't seem to make any comment on that. Voltage essentially the same, current capacity same or greater, and AC or DC as required.

Evidently the original is 11.5V AC at 1-2 amps or so (10-20W.) Which probably will work with 12VAC 2 or more amps.

Depending on internal circuitry, it might also work with 12VDC, though polarity might be important, or it might not work at all. Old, and that much power, it's probably an incandescent bulb and polarity agnostic (but also subject to filament breakage.) You might be able to find an LED replacement bulb, most of which would care about polarity.

The adapter you show is 12VDC. Odds are excellent you can find some 12VDC adapter around the house or at the thrift store (they are common) and try that for no or little money. Personally I'd replace the inappropriately used RCA plug, or just wire directly to the new supply with no plug.

Comment: FWIW an external hard drive case often has a 12V DC power supply rated at 2 A, might be a place to try if a computer user is in the area and has a spare power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter you show has an output of 12VDC and the specs for the adapter you listed as too expensive states 12VAC so it might not work the the lamp you have. Plus you'd have to change the low voltage socket. Some LEDs will work with AC or DC.

Checking for the specs, I found this site on Ebay that sells the adapter, used, that you're looking for. While we don't do shopping on this site, this popped up so I'm sharing it with you.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/354371917922?hash=item5282365862:g:QrYAAOSwHwdjY38W

[image]